# How to strip tags in Jquery DataTables

Tags: javascript, json, codeigniter, datatables

I am using CodeIgniter and DataTables([link](https://datatables.net/)) with library IgnitedDatatables([link](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables)).

I dont know how to use something like strip_tags() in DataTables. I just need to remove all html tag output from JSON data.

My JavaScript Code :

```js
var table = $('#dtslider').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: baseurl + 'admin/Administrator/getdata_slider',
    type: "POST"
  },
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  columns: [{
    data: "idHome",
    visible: false
  }, {
    data: "jdlHome"
  }, {
    data: "isiHome",
    sType: 'html'
  }, {
    data: "Actions",
    searchable: false
  }],
  "order": [
    [0, "asc"]
  ]
});
```

HTML Code :

```html
<div class="box-body">
  <div class="order-column">
    <table id="dtslider" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead class="dt-right">
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>Judul Panel</th>
          <th>Isi Panel</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.box-body -->
```

The output : 
[image]
In image ouput there are strong at row2 and pre at row 3. I need to remove all html tags at the output. I already try something like sType and createdrow, but still no result. maybe because i am still new at DataTables and JavaScript. Can someone help me?

Edit (more code) :

getdata_slider :

```html
public function getdata_slider()
 {
  $column = 'idHome, jdlHome, isiHome';
  $id     = 'idHome';
  $table  = 'home';
  $columnwhere = 'ketHome';
  $key  = '1';

  $this->Model_administrator->getDatatablesCustom2($column, $id, $table, $columnwhere, $key);
  echo $this->datatables->generate();
 }
```

getDatatablesCustom2 :

```html
public function getDatatablesCustom2($column, $id, $table, $columnwhere, $key)
 {
  $this->load->library('Datatables');
  $this->load->helper('Datatables_helper');
  $this->datatables->select($column)->where($columnwhere, $key)
  ->unset_column('file')
  ->add_column('file','<a href="'.base_url("assets/uploads/$1").'">$1</a>', 'file')
  ->add_column('Actions', get_buttons('$1'), $id)
  ->from($table);
 }
```

Comment: i guess this is a serverside issue - you should do this in your getdata_slider function

Comment: can you give me more pointer or example what must i do at getdata_slider? i write the code in the post just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sType, createRow, and even columnRender didnt do anything for me. I don't know the fault is in library, jquery, or the stupid me (70% fault in the latter of course.).

but, thankfully, i found edit_column at library function.

my code now look something like this :

```html
public function getDatatablesCustom2($column, $id, $table, $columnwhere, $key)
 {
  $this->load->library('Datatables');
  $this->load->helper('Datatables_helper');
  $this->datatables->select($column)->where($columnwhere, $key)
  ->unset_column('file')
  ->edit_column('isiHome', '$1', 'strip_tags(isiHome)')
  ->add_column('file','<a href="'.base_url("assets/uploads/$1").'">$1</a>', 'file')
  ->add_column('Actions', get_buttons('$1'), $id)
  ->from($table);
 }
```

thanks for all the pointer and help :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)-Option to manipulate the data before it is being rendered.